# Packaging by feature

Tags: java, package, project-management, setup-project

I'm trying to getting into understanding properly the package by feature approach.

> 1 - Let say I have 2 features that tap on the same data. For instance,
>   one feature could be visualizing bank account information with
>   different sophisticate possibilities. The other feature is about
>   making transaction from the bank account (We could well imagine that
>   this feature does not involve visualization, it could be simply
>   provided as a rest service).
>
> 1.a - The data model is shared across two features here. How does that impact the package by features. Shall we create redundant data models
>   class in the 2 package ? Shall we create a specific package for the
>   data model instead?

which leads me to the second question?

> 2- In general how are cross-cutting concern dealt with ?
>
> 2.a - For instance the case above when it comes to the data model?
>
> 2.b - Or, when it comes to the database access or some common access to an external service (shared by different feature but doing
>   something different with it)?
>
> 2.c - Else, the front-end or the overall bundling of the application in general.

What i mean here, is the following case: Currently i have an application which has

(i) a message transfer capability (between participant of the system)

(ii) It also has the messaging monitoring capability whereby it automatically detect rules     violation and give penalties.

(iii) A visualization capability dedicated to the administrator of the system.

(iv) A notification capability provided to the administrator of the system to send message to participants.

(V) A violation cancellation capability for the admin as well. And so on.

> The point is all of it has to be packaged in one application that i
>   call marketplace infrastructure. Should the marketplace infrastructure
>   that wires everything together have his own package ? Even if it is
>   not a feature.

I think the same could be applied some how in a Web-application as well. There has to be one central point that bundles all the feature modules / packages altogether. If each module define routes, controllers etc... There should be a central routes that import all routes for instance.

If the application has a database behind, this database is used by different feature, well who is going to start the database and wire every modules.

> So bottom line is: what about the cross functional stuff (data models,
>   service access and etc..) and the bundling (wiring everything
>   together).

PS: By wiring i think about dependency injection, still the graph of object has to be defined somewhere.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is package by feature approach good?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733267/is-package-by-feature-approach-good)

Comment: Well I'm not asking if it is good. I want to do and i red a lot about it. I just don't understand fully what is meant to be package in features and what is not. What is the extend of the methodology? How is it supposed to be applied?

Comment: There is more in that link than just 'is it good' ...

Comment: IMO, I think packages are just like organizing mails in folders. You'll always have one email that fits in more than one folder. That's because Gmail uses tags instead of folders, I guess. Of course, you may find some package structure that maximizes encapsulation, reuse, etc, but there will be always that case where your package structure is not right. So I would not worry about this TOO MUCH. Instead, try to find some organization that makes sense first and your software evolution will tell you which way to go.

Comment: Leo,  thank for taking the time. But your answer sounds like, let's go freestyle anyway. The comparison is not right to me either. Because in case of software encapsulation as you mention is very important in term of how you may grow the system and make some change. This problematic is not present in gmail. You want also to enforce a certain way of using your system, and etc.... So yes i think it matter. Probably some form of combination of the 2.

Comment: Meanwhile after reading around and around, I think one advantage of going by feature first is that it align itself well with the notion of TDD. It further stress the notion of refactoring. Indeed, when common things come up you should think about how to refactor it properly and create the appropriate package organization for it. You might want to group those feature that use this common things or you might want to create one package for it. It force you to be cohesive and properly think your encapsulation as well. But it will be an ongoing work, whereby you only build what you need.

Comment: You will probably end up having some layers which will be features in themselves with respect to your application. You application will become the client of this common packages.